# Exception on lambda expression ASP NET CORE EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, asp.net-core, ef-fluent-api

**Application Version:**

Asp Net Core 1.1

EF: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (1.1.1)

**Line:**

_dbContext.MyTable1.Include(c => c.MyIntermediateTable).ToList();

**Exception:**

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Invalid column name 'MyPK1'.
>
> Invalid column name 'MyPK1'.
>
> Invalid column name 'MyPK2'.
>
> Invalid column name 'MyPK1'.

**My Entities**

```
[Table("MyTable1")]
public class MyTable1
{
    public MyTable1()
    {
        MyIntermediateTable = new List<MyIntermediateTable>();
    }

    [Column("MyPK1")]
    public  int MyPK1 { get; set; }
    public  string Name{ get; set; } 

    public virtual List<MyIntermediateTable> MyIntermediateTable{ get; set; }
}

[Table("MyIntermediateTable")]
public class MyIntermediateTable
{

    public int MyPK1 { get; set; }
    public int MyPK2 { get; set; }
    public virtual MyTable1 MyTable1 { get; set; }
    public virtual MyTable2 MyTable2 { get; set; }
 }

[Table("MyTable2")]
public class MyTable2
{
    public MyTable2()
    {
         MyIntermediateTable = new List<MyIntermediateTable>();
    }

    [Column("MyPK2")]
    public int MyPK2 { get; set; }
    public  string Name{ get; set; } 

    public virtual List<MyIntermediateTable> MyIntermediateTable{ get; set; }

}
```

**Model Builder (Fluent API)**

```
       modelBuilder.Entity<MyIntermediateTable>((item) =>
        {
            item.HasKey(p => p.MyPK1);
            item.HasKey(p => p.MyPK2);
            item.HasOne(u => u.MyTable1).WithMany(u => u.MyIntermediateTable).HasForeignKey(u => u.MyPK1);
            item.HasOne(u => u.MyTable2).WithMany(u => u.MyIntermediateTable).HasForeignKey(u => u.MyPK2);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable1>((item) =>
        {
            item.HasKey(p => p.MyPK1);
            item.HasMany(u => u.MyIntermediateTable).WithOne(u => u.MyTable1).HasForeignKey(u => u.MyPK1);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable2>((item) =>
        {
            item.HasKey(p => p.MyPK2);
            item.HasMany(u => u.MyIntermediateTable).WithOne(u => u.MyTable2).HasForeignKey(u => u.MyPK2);
        });
```

Comment: Looks like your database doesn't match what EF thinks it should be?

Comment: did you deploy the latest migration? look at the tables with SQL server management studio or the server explorer that is integrated with VS, and see if the tables are actually missing those columns. if that is the case, update the schema.

Comment: `item.HasKey(p => p.MyPK1); item.HasKey(p => p.MyPK2);` should be `item.HasKey(p => new { p.MyPK1, p.MyPK2 });`. Also there is no need to configure one and the same relationship in two places.